# Attaching small, nearly zero weight cable clips directly to drywall without anchors

Tags: hanging, fastener

My project runs about 30ft of ethernet cable along garage (interior) walls. I have 5mm plastic R-Style clips and I need to put about 1 per foot (at least 30 clips).

I'm looking for something that I can attach these neatly without having to drive in anchors on every stop or comply with stud positions in the cable run. Maybe a product or fastener I've never heard of that you all may know about.

Alternatively, I'll just do my best to line them up with the studs or deal w/ anchors. Thanks for any ideas.

[image: clips]

Comment: I've used something like [this](https://www.amazon.com/eBoot-Pieces-Adhesive-Management-Holder/dp/B01HR9VS4I/ref=sr_1_8?keywords=cable+clips&qid=1578607082&sr=8-8) to organize ethernet cables along the baseboard of my home to avoid drilling or screwing things into the drywall.  Just a simple adhesive should be more than fine and will prevent you making 30 holes in the drywall.

Comment: @Steve-o169 I was unable to find 5mm white/clear. I think I figured out a solution here though. I'm actually attaching in the upper corner of the wall, there is wood behind it because it's in a corner so I'll be fine just screwing in. Maybe a couple I'll need to just attack to drywall or use an anchor :) - Appreciate the input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind what you're dealing with here.  *Drywall is chalk between 2 pieces of paper*.  Here, take a piece of chalkboard chalk. Soak strips of newspaper in 50/50 elmers glue and water mix, and roll them around the chalk.  Let dry.  *Congrats, you've made drywall*.

However, fragile as it is, an ethernet cable is a trivial load.  It'll be fine.

---

Just so you know, the National Electrical Code does have a chapter on **non-PoE** Ethernet wiring, it's in chapter 8 (800 *et.seq.*) And better, as Section 90.3 says, “Chapter 8 is not subject to the requirements of Chapter 1 through 7 except where the requirements are specifically referenced in Chapter 8.” So there are several ordinary requirements you can ignore.

However, chapter 1-7 requirements which prohibit data cables still apply.  You cannot use mains wiring or conduit as a *hanger* to support data cabling.  You cannot run data cabling inside a box or conduit containing mains wiring.  Code requires mains wiring to be able to contain an arc-fire event where insulation melts; and if a mains wire melted into comms wires, obviously it would put mains voltage on equipment not rated for it, which would spread the hazard.

If you're doing PoE, depending on the load that may push you into Class 2 or Class 3 wiring methods, but that's beyond the scope of your question.

Comment: Amazing and incredibly useful information - in scope or out. Thank you. It's PoE... I don't know the draw.

Comment: Drat @emmdee.  You'd need to figure out voltage and current, as it may kick you into one of the Class 2 or 3 wiring method.  Time for a new question on that.

Comment: Yea its just a residential camera. Not going to worry about it :)

Answer (score 2):

The Command brand of products includes [small clips designed to hang wiring](https://www.command.com/3M/en_US/command/products/~/Command-Small-Wire-Hooks/?N=5924736%203294529207%203294772789&rt=rud). There are lots of imitator products that use the same approach. They use the same flexible adhesive strip approach as larger Command hooks, which don't require drywall anchors, screws, or other fasteners. They make several styles of these small hooks besides the one I've linked to, so you may want to shop around to find the right version for your needs.

I'm not sure what your plastic R style clips are, but this style of clip is designed to have the wiring hung directly from it and don't require any other clip for the wiring. You may find that you don't need one per foot, I've hung wiring with these clips with only one per every three or four feet.

Comment: The difference is that the imitators will damage the wall when you remove them... in contrast, Command strips will damage the wall when you remove them, but it will be your fault because you removed them the *obvious* way instead of the *correct* way.  Nobody appreciates 3M's peculiar genius.

Comment: I'm looking for a clean, flush-as-possible look, not going to hang from hooks. Command products are awesome though I use them for all sorts of stuff!! Regarding the clips I'm using, there is a pic of the clips in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

Will it work with a Sheetrock screw yes it will Hold.
To make an almost invisible hanger look up “coologin” pro photo hooks or push pin hangers one add called the one pice a high heeled shoe style .
 I recommend the coologin and allow our renters to use them I have seen where the college boys hung all the hard wire internet connections on these and when they left took it all down with no real damage to the Sheetrock or trim they did reshape the hooks to hold cable, you could see where the pushed them into the trim but it was not obvious in the Sheetrock.